# selecting the index of radio button from a group of dynamically generated radio buttons in c# for windows phone

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7

The xaml contains:

```xaml
<RadioButton Content="{Binding Content}" Height="70" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="rbopt" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="False" FontSize="20"  Tag="{Binding Correct}" Click="radioButton1_Click_1" IsHitTestVisible="True" />
```

and we display the id of the selected radio button in a textblock as:

```xaml
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Height="225" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,28,0,0" Name="txtoptid"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" />
```

```cs
//table name is Options

private void radioButton1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        RadioButton radio = sender as RadioButton;

        //convert string to long

        string id = txtquesID.Text.ToString();
        long qid;
        long.TryParse(id, out qid);
        //getting count of number of options
        var opp = (from Option opt in catAppDB.Options where opt.Q_id==qid
                  select opt).Count();

         //getting the option records
        var opp1 = from Option opt in catAppDB.Options
                   where opt.Q_id == qid
                   select opt;

       var opt1list = opp1.ToList();

       for (int i = 0; i < opp; i++)
       {
           //following loop gets executed opp times because for any option selected in the group,radio.IsChecked is always true hence it displays the id of the last option in the radio button group,it should get executed only once.
           if (radio.IsChecked == true)    
           {
               txtoptid.Text = "";
               var opt2 = opt1list[i] as Option;
               var opt3 = opt2._id;
               txtoptid.Text = opt3.ToString();
           }
       } }
```

I am trying to select the index of a particular radio button which the user clicks on but the radio.IsChecked becomes true for any radio button we click. Kindly help us solve this doubt. With the above code the last index of the radio button in the group gets selected but we want the index of the selected radio. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you generate the RadioButtons in code behind?

Comment: I am adding the options dynamically from the database. I am binding the options in the pivot items and the radio buttons get generated dynamically based on number of options in table i.e. 3 radio buttons if a question has 3 options and 4 for 4 options.